# xbox 360, unrecognized disk error 03-57-00

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

I got an error message from my xbox 360. 03-57-00.

I followed the recommendations given by xbox. Now I was attempting to play a disk that I had played earlier and left in the machine.

When I returned I had the error code "unrecognized disk error: 03-57-00". I checked and cleaned the disk I had been using. Still I received the  same error code again. I tried another 3 disks, but with no success. Even cleaning with a lens cleaner did not help. I unplugged the Skylanders portal and the Disney 3.0 portal as well as both controllers. Again, I got the same error code.

At this point I opened the disk tray. I then made a note of which way the title was facing. I attempted to run the disk again, but I got the same error code. However I noticed that the title of the disk was in the same spot from when I closed the disk tray. I tried this several more times. Each time the disk title stayed in the same spot.

I did this again with two other disks. Same result. I also had unplugged everything from USB ports.

So the question I have is this: What else can I do to get around this error message? Or does this sound like the motor that turns the disk gave out? I really need to know. Thank you for your time and effort to help me.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade Greg. Have you tried another disc, does those work? Also regarding, "I'm tired of going to web sties to ask a question and only to find out you can't ask your question unless you join their web following. I hate that! I do not want to join your web site to use it only once to ask questions. Don't give the option to contact you if you are going to horse me to join to get an anwser to my questions. It's stinks." we aren't a support channel, we are like a forum, and on this "forum", we ask people to register so that we can keep spam off, and you'll get notifications with mail.

Comment: what?  really!? Did you really read my post? I tried 4 x box disks and a lens cleaning disk. Nothing worked. So could it be the motor that turns the disk? or something else? I know a good place near me that will fix this if it is a motor problem.  im open to ideas.

Comment: It is probably the optical drive then, I'd recommend taking it to somewhere that can fix it.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds broke. Gonna need fixed or replaced if it's not even spinning.

Answer (score 1):

Sad to hear that.

Seems like your disk reader got crap'd up. You should go to a repair service somewhere.

Also, it doesn't seem like a disk reader problem, try to put the disk into another xbox.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I read that your disc title seems to maintain the same orientation even after inserting a disc. The Xbox 360 should automatically spin up to read the disc, so this could either indicate the unit isn't sensing that the tray is closed or your motor may be faulty.

- If the motor is bad, you will need to replace the entire drive with the *exact* same model
- If the motor is not faulty, try cleaning the laser's lens (recommend taking the disc drive apart, though this voids the warranty)
- If cleaning the lens doesn't solve the problem, try the process outlined here: http://team-xecuter.com/forums/threads/61768-Disc-Read-problems-How-to-POT-Tweak-Xbox-360-DVD-Laser

### Retuning the Laser Diode Potentiometer

A laser needs to be supplied power at an optimum voltage range in order to work properly. Too little, and it can't properly reflect light off the disc to read it. Too much, and it will burn out. The following procedure will ensure your laser is tuned properly to read discs.

1. Take Xbox 360 unit apart (VOIDS WARRANTY, but it's likely expired)
2. Use a digital multimeter to measure the laser's DVD potentiometer and adjust if neccessary
3. Test the cleanest, least scratched disc you have available

**Fractions of a degree are the difference between a proper setting and burning out your laser diode, which is why a digital multimeter is neccessary!**

The pictures in the guide above aren't showing up, but I can't post clarifying ones because of my limited privileges as a new user here. A Google Image search will help to find the proper measuring points for your specific disc drive model.

This picture outlines the various disc drive versions between Xbox 360 models:
[image]

Following the above process, I brought my friend's 10 year old Xbox 360 back to life (he thought it was junk). Hope this helps! ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try it in another Xbox 360, I had a similar issue and it worked in another Xbox.

It could also be that the disk is scratched.

Comment: How does this help solve the problem? OP asked what they could do to get around this.